# visjs timeline another calender (not Gregorian calendar)

Tags: calendar, momentjs, timeline, vis.js

hey I want to use solar calender in timeline visjs
I have tried using moment-jalali but it didn't work.

is there anybody have used this library with another calender?

tnx in advance

Comment: What did not work?

Comment: I want to use solar calender instead Gregorian calendar , I dont know how

Comment: I want to give the start data in gregorian calender and then visjs draw the chart timeline in solar calender with the help of moment-jalali library ro sth else. I dont know is there any option in visjs to change the calender or not?